# pandas str.split is giving me an unexpected syntax error

Tags: python, pandas, split, syntax-error

I am trying to replace column values with only the part of the string contained between two '.' using the split function. Here is the line I am using:

```
df["Sample"] = df["Sample"].str.split(".").str[1]
```

I have also tried using the following, but had the same problem:

```
df["Sample"] = df["Sample"].str.split(".",maxsplit=1)
```

When I run the code I receive the following syntax error:

```
df = df.drop(["Sample", "percent", "Reads"], axis=1)
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I tried running the code without the above line, the syntax error appeared on a different and also previously functioning line, so I do think the problem is related to the new line.

This is the complete code

```
import pandas as pd 
import glob

file_list = glob.glob("file paths here")
for f in file_list:
    df = []
    outFile = f.replace('Eukaryota_phylum','relative_abundance') 
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t", header=None)

    df.columns = ["Sample", "percent", "Reads", "Taxon_ID", "Phylum"]
    df["Sample"] = df["Sample"].str.split(".").str[1]
    df["Phylum"] = df["Phylum"].str.replace("Eukaryota;"," ")
    df["Phylum"] = df["Phylum"].str.replace(";", " ")

    df["Reads"] = df["Reads"].astype(float)
    df["Percent_Reads"] = 100*df["Reads"]/df["Reads"].sum()

    df = df.rename(columns={"Percent_Reads": "Percent_Reads_"+str(df["Sample"])
    df = df.drop(["Sample", "percent", "Reads"], axis=1)

    with open(outFile, "w") as f_out:
        df.to_csv(f_out, sep="\t", index=None, header=True)
```

Comment: What's your syntax error? `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'`?

Comment: @Superdude      ` df = df.drop(["Sample", "percent", "Reads"], axis=1)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`      and the error never appears on the line I believe is causing me problems

Comment: also how do I make things show up as code in my comments? I am new to this website and thought the back tick should work but it isnt showing up? I edited the original post to include the syntax error as a code block.

Comment: It sounds like you fixed the SyntaxError based on axelschmidt's answer. Please edit your post with the corrected code and the full text of the error you are now getting. You should also include a small sample of your data.

Answer (score 1):

In the line above `df = df.drop(["Sample", "percent", "Reads"], axis=1)` you are missing the closing `}` and `)`.

Try:

```
df = df.rename(columns={"Percent_Reads": "Percent_Reads_"+str(df["Sample"])})
```

Comment: Thank you, it must have gotten deleted however when I add it back in the same problem still occurs.